# Using external non-Android Java library in Android: couldn't find .so file and so on

Tags: java, android, jar, .so, gf

I'm trying to build a template Android app using [Grammatical Framework's Java bindings](https://github.com/GrammaticalFramework/gf-core/tree/master/src/runtime/java) (however, I don't think what Java code I'm using in particular actually matters. Let's just say I'm trying to use some external non-Android Java code in an Android app).

After some trial and error, I got to successfully *build* an app using this external code by following these steps:

1. generating a `.jar` file for the library I want to use (it's called `jpgf.jar`
2. copying it to `app/libs`
3. adding it as a library and verifying that the `build.gradle` gets updated with

   ```
    implementation files('libs/jpgf.jar')
   ```
4. importing it in my app's `MainActivity` and writing some code that uses it

However, nothing can be easy in Android development, ever. So my app, after nicely compiling, crashes on startup with the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/bho.harisont.gfdemo-8c870hpW06uEnMQHV1ILjw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/bho.harisont.gfdemo-8c870hpW06uEnMQHV1ILjw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]] couldn't find "libjpgf.so"
```

In short, some `.so` file can't be found. Now, I'm not Java or `.so` file expert, but I do know that when I installed `jpgf` system-wide on my machine using the dedicated `Makefile`, a `.so` file was generated and copied to some location. My probably naive attempt was to take that `.so` file and move it to the appropriate subfolder of `jniLibs`. I know I placed it in the correct folder and all, because in this way I managed to change the error message, but not to solve the problem: at this point the complaint is that `libjpgf.so` is 64 instead of 32 bits. You bet, my machine is 64 bits.

So, to help me you can answer one both of these questions:

- how do I compile a 32 bit version of the `.so` file on a 64 bit machine? I tried some `gcc` options but it's not like that helped
- do I actually need that prebuilt `.so` file? I see other people just importing JARs. Can I not just do that (or even import the source code somehow), and have Android Studio generate all the assets it wants the way it wants?

Comment: More things I already tried: adding `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` to the app's `build.gradle`; clean building; "building" (?) `jpgf.jar` from Android Studio